# How to test NSLog in testing framework (default iOS)

Tags: ios, unit-testing

Does anyone know how to write a unit test for `NSLog` functionality?
I am writing unit tests for all my framework components and it's very import to me to test if logging occurs in various scenarios.

Ex: A configuration that allows a user of your framework to enable or disable logging. It is important that logging occurs if they enable it but this is difficult to verify in unit tests.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: My question is, when you do NSLog how do I write a unit test case that will tell me does nslog printed on console or not ? Does that explain my question @H2CO3.

Comment: It doesn't, since `NSLog()` always prints if you call it...

Comment: Maybe you can replace the NSLog implementation with a macro # define DLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);

Comment: @ScottBossak - You should have used acute accents around that line -- most of your underscores turned into __bold__ characters.

Comment: I encourage you to open a new question, but use the wording from your comment explaining what you mean. That is, how to write a unit test that ensures something specific was written to NSLog.

Comment: This is an older post but I disagree that this is a stupid question. Wanted to know if a method was invoked is dependent on your conditional logic, if the only side effect is that NSLog is called then knowing whether or not that happened is important to being able to verify your logic. This should not have been closed.

Comment: @Joe You make a compelling case. I've re-opened. Please submit an edit if you can clarify the question further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way to test is, do NSLog and then check the console log. And code to check that

```
    NSMutableArray *consoleLog = [NSMutableArray array];

aslclient client = asl_open(NULL, NULL, ASL_OPT_STDERR);

aslmsg query = asl_new(ASL_TYPE_QUERY);
asl_set_query(query, ASL_KEY_MSG, NULL, ASL_QUERY_OP_NOT_EQUAL);
aslresponse response = asl_search(client, query);

asl_free(query);

aslmsg message;
while((message = aslresponse_next(response)))
{
    const char *msg = asl_get(message, ASL_KEY_MSG);
    [consoleLog addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s" , msg]];
}

NSLog(@"Console: %@", consoleLog);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend writing a wrapper for NSLog and testing that wrapper thoroughly. Example: you have a class `URLStringValidator` that exists to validate url strings.

You want to log a message if an empty `String` is passed in. You would make a protocol to represent your logger.

```swift
protocol Logging {
    func log(_ message: String, args: CVarArg...)
}

struct Logger: Logging {
    func log(_ message: String, args: CVarArg...) {
        NSLog(message, args)
    }
}

class URLValidator {
    let logger: Logging

    init(logger: Logging = Logger()) {
        self.logger = logger
    }

    func isEmpty(urlString: String) -> Bool {
        guard !urlString.isEmpty else {
            logger.log("Don't pass an empty string")
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Now you can use a fake instead of `Logger`. I would also argue that you need an additional test to assert that logger has a concrete implementation of the correct type. ex:

```swift
class FakeLogger: Logging {
    var capturedMessage: String?

    func log(_ message: String, args: CVarArg...) {
        capturedMessage = message
    }
}

class URLValidatorTests {
    func testLoggerDefaults() {
        XCTAssertTrue(URLValidator().logger is Logger,
                      "A url validator should use the correct concrete class for its logger")
    }

    func testValidatingEmptyString() {
        let fakeLogger = FakeLogger()
        let validator = URLValidator(logger: fakeLogger)

        validator.isEmpty(urlString: "")
        XCTAssertNil(fakeLogger.capturedMessage)

        validator.isEmpty(urlString: "Not Empty")
        XCTAssertEqual(fakeLogger.capturedMessage, "Don't pass an empty string")
    }
}
```

Now you can test your logic (the part you care about and should be testing) and leave `NSLog` as a configuration detail. You could just as easy use `os_log` or write to a custom file.